# Debug Console REPL not responding to a debug session. Not able to interact with

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

So today when debugging my TypeScript code I've run into a pretty abtritary error in VSCode. When starting a debug session. I was not able to interact with the "DEBUG CONSOLE". The "DEBUG CONSOLE" window just didn't respond. It seems that the "DEBUG CONSOLE" tab does not receive any information from my browser (chrome).

my launch.json:

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8100",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is to specify the "outputCapture" to "console". After that, the "DEBUG CONSOLE" worked again. Maybe it changed it somehow internally without me knowing it. Hope it helps for somebody who is facing the same problem

```js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Edge against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8100",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "outputCapture": "console",
      }
    ]
}
```